# 'LookupAlignConvolution2d' no object '_convolution_op' attribute error

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I have been working with the project tf-lcnn (https://github.com/ildoonet/tf-lcnn). I have built tensorflow from sources (1.4.1) and I am using python3 to run the command `python3 train.py`. This issue is that when I run said command I get:

```
AttributeError: 'LookupAlignConvolution2d' object has no attribute '_convolution_op'
```

I have tried tensorflow versions(1.3 and 1.4) and nothing gets the project to work. The custom_op was linked properly and works. The instructions from the project don't state that you have to follow his instructions first then build tensorflow. He also doesn't express the configuration build that he used.

I have tried some different approaches but I am sure there is something I am missing or doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. I can post additional information upon request. Thanks in advance!